# Forgot name of Java HTML framework

Tags: java, frameworks, html-generation

It may sound stupid, but I'm using a small framework for html generation containing of 3 classes:

- `Tag extends LinkedList`
- `Attribute`
- `Attributes extends LinkedList<Attribute>`

(I have the source code)

However, excessive googling (also with source code) didn't help much, just gave me the link to a (fitting) file `people.cs.uct.ac.za/~bfry/.../Tag.java`, but manually inspecting its homepage didn't help...

Does someone know this framework, I would like to refer to it in a tutorial...

Comment: I found references [here](https://bitbucket.org/javydreamercsw/jwrestling/src/1c44c7c8d156/jWrestlingLibs/html/Tag.java), [here](http://jsystemtest.sourceforge.net/doc/api/jsystem/extensions/report/html/summary/Tag.html), [here](http://code.google.com/p/languageemulationsoftware/source/browse/trunk/LES/html/Tag.java?r=123), and [here](http://svn2.assembla.com/svn/InfRetr/InfRetr2/src/infretr2/l2query/html/Tag.java).  It appears to be a couple of class files that are being manually shared between different projects, but I can't find any master source for them or any referenced license.

Comment: Hmm yeah, but I'm pretty sure there was a special website and it had its own name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first source I linked in my comment, if you go up a directory to `/html/`, it has both a [Readme](https://bitbucket.org/javydreamercsw/jwrestling/src/1c44c7c8d156/jWrestlingLibs/html/README) and [License](https://bitbucket.org/javydreamercsw/jwrestling/src/1c44c7c8d156/jWrestlingLibs/html/COPYING) file.  The readme references a project called **`Java HTML Generator`** from `http://artho.com/webtools/java-html-gen/`, which appears to be a broken link.

However, you can view what it *used* to look like in the Internet Archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20100216045834/http://artho.com/webtools/java/index.shtml

Comment: Exactly, that's it! I had already thought it might have gone offline... Thanks!

Comment: BTW, it seems to be back online under another link: http://artho.com/webtools/java/index.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Is this it?

OUnit - http://code.google.com/p/ounit/source/browse/ounit-htmlgen/src/main/java/com/googlecode/ounit/html/Tag.java?spec=svn598edaa4f8fbec9b15c0df5fbfaa0ee43b732b60&name=598edaa4f8&r=598edaa4f8fbec9b15c0df5fbfaa0ee43b732b60

Comment: No... you can find the source code the OP is referring to here: http://people.cs.uct.ac.za/~bfry/hsxshu003/.  Your linked implementation doesn't match.